# DocuSign API: Trying to move envelopes and getting error

Tags: c#, docusignapi

relatively new to SO so be easy on me :)

Anyways, I am using the C# DocuSign API to try and move some envelopes from one folder to another.  I'm getting an "Invalid response type." exception however, even though the envelopes are actually being moved as expected.  Here is my code - can anyone immediately spot what I'm doing wrong here or how to call this function without getting an exception?

```
namespace DocuSign.RetrieveEnvelopes
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static readonly EnvelopesApi _envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();
        private static readonly FoldersApi _foldersApi = new FoldersApi();
        private static readonly FoldersRequest _foldersRequest = new FoldersRequest();
        private static Folder targetFolder;
        private static Folder fromFolder;

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                DocuSignUtils.ConfigureApiClient();
                Config.AccountId = DocuSignUtils.Authenticate();

                var folders = _foldersApi.List(Config.AccountId);
                _foldersRequest.EnvelopeIds = new List<string>();

                foreach (var foldr in folders.Folders)
                {
                    if (foldr.Name == "Completed") { targetFolder = foldr; }
                    else if (foldr.Name == "Sent Items") { fromFolder = foldr; }
                }

                var envelops = _foldersApi.ListItems(Config.AccountId, fromFolder.FolderId);

                foreach (FolderItem fItem in envelops.FolderItems)
                {
                    Envelope eItem = _envelopesApi.GetEnvelope(Config.AccountId, fItem.EnvelopeId);

                    if (eItem.Status == "completed")
                    {
                        _foldersRequest.EnvelopeIds.Add(eItem.EnvelopeId);

                        var docItem = _envelopesApi.GetDocument(Config.AccountId, eItem.EnvelopeId, "combined");
                        var fStream = File.Create("C:\\Temp\\data\\" + eItem.EmailSubject.ToString() + ".pdf");
                        docItem.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                        docItem.CopyTo(fStream);
                        fStream.Close();

                    }
                }


                if (_foldersRequest.EnvelopeIds.Count >= 1)
                {
                    FoldersResponse fResponse = _foldersApi.MoveEnvelopes(Config.AccountId, targetFolder.FolderId, _foldersRequest);
                }
                
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                RetrieveEnvelopsErrorHandler.LogException(ex);
            }
        }
}
```

Note: _foldersApi is a FoldersAPI object and _foldersRequest is a FoldersRequest object with envelope ids of the envelopes I'd like to move.  Also, I tried just calling this function directly without assigning the return value to a FoldersResponse var but it gave the same error.

Stack Trace:

```
" at DocuSign.eSign.Client.ApiClient.Deserialize(Byte[] content, Type type, IList`1 headers)\r\n   at DocuSign.eSign.Api.FoldersApi.MoveEnvelopesWithHttpInfo(String accountId, String folderId, FoldersRequest foldersRequest)\r\n   at DocuSign.eSign.Api.FoldersApi.MoveEnvelopes(String accountId, String folderId, FoldersRequest foldersRequest)\r\n   at DocuSign.RetrieveEnvelopes.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\\DocuSign\\DocuSign.RetrieveEnvelopes\\Program.cs:line 73"
```

Comment: this is probably a bug, we can open a ticket and investigate. Do you get an exception thrown?. or is this just in the fResponse? if the latter - can you just ignore?

Comment: It's an exception caught by the try/catch.  I can send you a stack trace if you'd like.

Comment: if you can update the question to include the rest of the code and the exception - that would help

Comment: @InbarGazit added

Comment: what is the content of the _foldersRequest object? can you post the rest of your code?

Comment: it has to have both the envelopeIDs as well as the folderIDs of the folders

Comment: @InbarGazit added the rest of the code.  I may have missed a bracket or two somewhere in the copy/paste/remove excess but you get the idea.  Thanks in advance for looking at this for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is corrected code with latest Nuget (SDK):

```
        FoldersApi _foldersApi = new FoldersApi(apiClient);

        FoldersRequest _foldersRequest = new FoldersRequest();
        var folders = _foldersApi.List(accountId);
        _foldersRequest.EnvelopeIds = new List<string>();

        Folder fromFolder = new Folder();
        Folder targetFolder = new Folder();
        foreach (var foldr in folders.Folders)
        {
            if (foldr.Name == "Completed") { targetFolder = foldr; }
            else if (foldr.Name == "Sent Items") { fromFolder = foldr; }
        }

        var envelops = _foldersApi.ListItems(accountId, fromFolder.FolderId);
        foreach (Folder folder in envelops.Folders)
        {
            foreach (FolderItemV2 fItem in folder.FolderItems)
            {
                Envelope eItem = envelopesApi.GetEnvelope(accountId, fItem.EnvelopeId);

                if (eItem.Status == "completed")
                {
                    _foldersRequest.EnvelopeIds.Add(eItem.EnvelopeId);

                    var docItem = envelopesApi.GetDocument(accountId, eItem.EnvelopeId, "combined");
                    var fStream = File.Create("C:\\Temp\\data\\" + eItem.EmailSubject.ToString() + ".pdf");
                    docItem.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    docItem.CopyTo(fStream);
                    fStream.Close();

                }
            }
        }


        if (_foldersRequest.EnvelopeIds.Count >= 1)
        {
            FoldersResponse fResponse = _foldersApi.MoveEnvelopes(accountId, targetFolder.FolderId, _foldersRequest);
        }
    }
```